# React Native - passing data model from Flat list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a FlatList:

```
<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
            <Screen style={styles.screen}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ProfileDetailScreen")}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={users}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.uid}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Screen>
        </ScrollView>
```

And Im getting some data from firebase like:

```
useEffect(() => {
        firebaseUsers
            .onSnapshot(
                querySnapshot => {
                    const newUsers = []
                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        const user = doc.data()
                        user.id = doc.id
                        newUsers.push(user)
                    });
                    setUsers(newUsers)
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            )
    }, [])
```

The data I get from firebase has `name`, `image` and `age` (and more more fields).

How can I pass all the data for a single user into the `ProfileDetailedScreen`?

Not sure the correct way to achieve this (not sure If I need to create data models etc?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know firebase that well but I have experience in RN. From what I'm understanding, you're going to want to make the `renderItem` function in your `FlatList` a function that returns a `TouchableOpacity` with navigation to the `ProfileDetailedScreen` component while also passing the user object. You'll display the user details in the `ProfileDetailedScreen`.
[Passing items in navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

```
/* 'item' is a user from the users array you passed into the data property of your FlatList above */
renderItem = ({item}) => (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ProfileDetailScreen", item)}>
      <Text> item?.name </Text> {/* show brief info about user */}
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

If you're using Redux for your application state, you could also navigate only to "ProfileDetailScreen" and dispatch an action that sets a `currentUser` in state. Your "ProfileDetailsScreen" would then pull the `currentUser` from state. This way has more moving parts but the component piece would look something like this:

```
/* 'item' is a user from the users array you passed into the data property in your FlatList above */
renderItem = ({item}) => (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setUserAndNavigate.bind(this, item)}>
      <Text> item?.name </Text> {/* show brief info about user */}
    </TouchableOpacity>
)

setUserAndNavigate = (user) => {
   this.props.setUser(user);
   navigation.navigate("ProfileDetailScreen");
}
```